# Django Url Error: Unknown Specifier ?P\d

Tags: django

My urls.py file is this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^chat/(?P\d+)/$', views.chatindex_view, name='chatindex_view'),
]
```

and I'm getting this error while executing the runserver command:

```
in regex (regex, six.text_type(e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: "^chat/(?P\d+)/$" is not a valid regular expression: unknown specifier: ?P\d
```

Comment: `?P` introduces a keyword match in your regex, but you haven't actually given a keyword.

Answer (score 4):

That's not valid. Where is the keyword argument you are trying to get ?

```
url(r'^chat/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.chatindex_view, name='chatindex_view'),
```